# Incorrect Data from ReadAsAsync

Tags: c#, backend

I'm debugging the backend of my application and noticing a discrepancy of a piece of data between the moment that it is sent, and the moment that it is received.

When I send the data, I use a certain model. Suppose:

```
public string Age { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Occupation { get; set; }
public string Sex { get; set; }
```

When I initially send the model, all of its fields are correctly set. When I receive the object, it is missing `Name` and `Occupation`.

The model is the same on each end, the only thing different is the name.

Here's how I send and receive the data:

```
using (var response = await RawGetAsync(cancellationToken, $"my/custom/endpoint/{customer}").ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response.StatusCode);
    }

    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyModel>(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: What serialisation mechanism do you use?
Just to clarify, are those missing fields set when you send the data? Could you, please provide a representation of the data you're sending and the data you're getting on the other side?

Comment: @DavidFulop How can I tell which serialisation method I am using? Also, yes, those missing fields are set when the data is sent. The model used for the data is the same on the sending and receiving side.

Comment: There's just not enough informaton here for us to help. Please show the code that sends the data, and what is `RawGetAsync`?

Comment: @User5842 If you didn't set the serialisation, it'll use whatever has been set up as default for the framework you're using. Are you using Web API on the server side, or perhaps WCF?